# Object.entries and flatMap handle null value

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have an function to transform data but the problem is when it comes to null value the Object.entries and flatMap it show an error like this, which it cannot read the null object or undefined object:

```
    Object.entries(val).map(([k, v]) => [key + '_' + k, v]) : 
             ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/tmp/puFsbRMXEh.js:6:14)
    at Array.flatMap (<anonymous>)
    at /tmp/puFsbRMXEh.js:3:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at transform (/tmp/puFsbRMXEh.js:1:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/puFsbRMXEh.js:95:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
```

here is my code:

```
const transform = data => data.map(el =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(el).flatMap(
        
      ([key, val]) => val === null ? 
      Object.entries(val).map(([k, v]) => [key + '_' + k, v]) : 
      [[key, val]] ,
    ([key, val]) => val && typeof val === 'object' ? 
      Object.entries(val).map(([k, v]) => [key + '_' + k, v]) : 
      [[key, val]],
      )
    )
  )




const data = [{
    id: '6397f6f46b18bc89cb37053c',
    cost_center: null,
    plant: null,
    material: null
  },
  {
    id: '6397f7166b18bc89cb372ff7',
    cost_center: 'C118as0008',
    short_description: 'LINE PasdNG ALL',
    plant: 'K1as8',
    material: '300006',
    material_name: 'DRILLO PBJ 22g MT (12 pcs x 8 ib)',
    base_quantity: 218.995,
    ZAP_DP: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_DP',
      stdval: 0.224,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    ZAP_EL: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_EL',
      stdval: 0.224,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    ZAP_LH: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_LH',
      stdval: 0.224,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    ZAP_OT: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_OT',
      stdval: 0.224,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    kwh: 35.46,
    no_mc_mmbtu: 5,
    noempl: 50
  },
  {
    id: '6397f7166b18bc89cb373003',
    cost_center: 'C11asd9',
    short_description: 'LINE WAasdAT FOX',
    plant: 'K1aas8',
    material: '300007',
    material_name: 'asBAasd0g GT (60 pcs)',
    base_quantity: 28.816,
    ZAP_DP: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_DP',
      stdval: 0.33,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    ZAP_EL: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_EL',
      stdval: 0.33,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    ZAP_GS: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_GS',
      stdval: 0.33,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    ZAP_LH: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_LH',
      stdval: 0.33,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    ZAP_OT: {
      acttyp: 'ZAP_OT',
      stdval: 0.33,
      unit: 'HR'
    },
    kwh: 72.67,
    no_mc_mmbtu: 1.85,
    noempl: 14.5
  }
]

console.log(transform(data))
```

Is that possible to change the null value into this, or can someone pointed out where did i do wrong here?

```
[
  {
    "id": "6397f6f46b18bc89cb37053c",
    "cost_center": "",
    "plant": "",
    "material": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "6397f7166b18bc89cb372ff7",
    "cost_center": "C118as0008",
    "short_description": "LINE PasdNG ALL",
    "plant": "K1as8",
    "material": "300006",
    "material_name": "DRILLO PBJ 22g MT (12 pcs x 8 ib)",
    "base_quantity": 218.995,
    "ZAP_DP_acttyp": "ZAP_DP",
    "ZAP_DP_stdval": 0.224,
    "ZAP_DP_unit": "HR",
    "ZAP_EL_acttyp": "ZAP_EL",
    "ZAP_EL_stdval": 0.224,
    "ZAP_EL_unit": "HR",
    "ZAP_LH_acttyp": "ZAP_LH",
    "ZAP_LH_stdval": 0.224,
    "ZAP_LH_unit": "HR",
    "ZAP_OT_acttyp": "ZAP_OT",
    "ZAP_OT_stdval": 0.224,
    "ZAP_OT_unit": "HR",
    "kwh": 35.46,
    "no_mc_mmbtu": 5,
    "noempl": 50
  },
...]
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the answer that was given in your previous question? [Restructure Array of object javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74991773) what doesn't work in that? Your modified code doesn't make much sense, `.flatMap()` doesn't accept two callbacks (the second argument acts as the `this` in the first callback, whic has no effect here).

Comment: because it still has null value on the object, i have to change it into "", ur code works perfectly but still i have to change the null value..., any help on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing two callback functions to [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) makes little sense. The first argument for `.flatMap()` should be the callback, and the second argument is the `thisArg` which specifies what `this` is inside of the callback function (which is not useful when the callback argument is an arrow function).

Instead, just use the second callback function you have (as this contains the most correct code), and convert the values to `""` if they are `null` when mapping your entries. Below I've made a helper function that checks if the value is `null` and if it is, it returns `""`, otherwise it returns the current value. I've used this helper function when flattening the inner objects as well as when mapping the standard keys:

```js
const transform = data => data.map(el =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(el).flatMap(
      ([key, val]) => val && typeof val === 'object' 
        ? Object.entries(val).map(([k, v]) => [key + '_' + k, nullToStr(v)]) 
        : [[key, nullToStr(val)]]
    )
  )
);

const nullToStr = (v) => v === null ? "" : v;

const data = [{ id: '6397f6f46b18bc89cb37053c', cost_center: null, plant: null, material: null }, { id: '6397f7166b18bc89cb372ff7', cost_center: 'C118as0008', short_description: 'LINE PasdNG ALL', plant: 'K1as8', material: '300006', material_name: 'DRILLO PBJ 22g MT (12 pcs x 8 ib)', base_quantity: 218.995, ZAP_DP: { acttyp: 'ZAP_DP', stdval: 0.224, unit: 'HR' }, ZAP_EL: { acttyp: 'ZAP_EL', stdval: 0.224, unit: 'HR' }, ZAP_LH: { acttyp: 'ZAP_LH', stdval: 0.224, unit: 'HR' }, ZAP_OT: { acttyp: 'ZAP_OT', stdval: 0.224, unit: 'HR' }, kwh: 35.46, no_mc_mmbtu: 5, noempl: 50 }, { id: '6397f7166b18bc89cb373003', cost_center: 'C11asd9', short_description: 'LINE WAasdAT FOX', plant: 'K1aas8', material: '300007', material_name: 'asBAasd0g GT (60 pcs)', base_quantity: 28.816, ZAP_DP: { acttyp: 'ZAP_DP', stdval: 0.33, unit: 'HR' }, ZAP_EL: { acttyp: 'ZAP_EL', stdval: 0.33, unit: 'HR' }, ZAP_GS: { acttyp: 'ZAP_GS', stdval: 0.33, unit: 'HR' }, ZAP_LH: { acttyp: 'ZAP_LH', stdval: 0.33, unit: 'HR' }, ZAP_OT: { acttyp: 'ZAP_OT', stdval: 0.33, unit: 'HR' }, kwh: 72.67, no_mc_mmbtu: 1.85, noempl: 14.5 } ];

console.log(transform(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `val` is `truthy`:

```js
const data = [{id: '6397f6f46b18bc89cb37053c',cost_center: null,plant: null,material: null,},{id: '6397f7166b18bc89cb372ff7',cost_center: 'C118as0008',short_description: 'LINE PasdNG ALL',plant: 'K1as8',material: '300006',material_name: 'DRILLO PBJ 22g MT (12 pcs x 8 ib)',base_quantity: 218.995,ZAP_DP: {acttyp: 'ZAP_DP',stdval: 0.224,unit: 'HR',},ZAP_EL: {acttyp: 'ZAP_EL',stdval: 0.224,unit: 'HR',},ZAP_LH: {acttyp: 'ZAP_LH',stdval: 0.224,unit: 'HR',},ZAP_OT: {acttyp: 'ZAP_OT',stdval: 0.224,unit: 'HR',},kwh: 35.46,no_mc_mmbtu: 5,noempl: 50,},{id: '6397f7166b18bc89cb373003',cost_center: 'C11asd9',short_description: 'LINE WAasdAT FOX',plant: 'K1aas8',material: '300007',material_name: 'asBAasd0g GT (60 pcs)',base_quantity: 28.816,ZAP_DP: {acttyp: 'ZAP_DP',stdval: 0.33,unit: 'HR',},ZAP_EL: {acttyp: 'ZAP_EL',stdval: 0.33,unit: 'HR',},ZAP_GS: {acttyp: 'ZAP_GS',stdval: 0.33,unit: 'HR',},ZAP_LH: {acttyp: 'ZAP_LH',stdval: 0.33,unit: 'HR',},ZAP_OT: {acttyp: 'ZAP_OT',stdval: 0.33,unit: 'HR',},kwh: 72.67,no_mc_mmbtu: 1.85,noempl: 14.5,},]

const transform = data =>
  data.map(el =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(el).flatMap(([k, v]) =>
        v?.constructor === Object 
          ? Object.entries(v).map(([k, v]) => [k + '_' + k, v ?? '']) 
          : [[k, v ?? '']]
      )
    )
  )

console.log(transform(data))
```

Comment: it works but not the result as i want... can u check my question again sir?.... @YosvelQuintero

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by assigning an empty string for null and undefined by using [`nullish coalescing (??)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) operator.

```
data.map(el => {
    Object.keys(el).forEach(key => {
    el[key] = el[key] ?? ''
  })
})
```